# Slack desktop client with socks proxy

Tags: proxy, socks5, slack

How can I configure slack desktop client to use a socks proxy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this command on Linux:

```
slack --proxy-server='socks5://localhost:1080'
```

Obviously, you could use this for http proxy:

```
slack --proxy-server='http://localhost:3128'
```